# python-igraph number of vertices

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I am using python-igraph package to create a graph from my edges stored in a file. I use Graph.Read_Edgelist to read the edges and create my desired graph. When I need to get the number of vertices in my graph I use the Graph.vcount() function which is supposed to return number of vertices which is not the case for me. For a file like this:

```
1 2
5 300
```

This function returns 301 which is not what I am looking for ! I need it to return 4 which is the actual number of vertices of my graph. Any idea what I can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved my problem using the following function instead of Graph.Read_Edgelist:

```
Graph.Read_Ncol(netFile, names=True, weights="if_present", directed=True)
```

By setting "name=True" the function considers the nodes numbers as their name and solves the vcount problem.