# Initial node's ids when creating graph from edge list

Tags: python, igraph

I wonder, where does the function [Read_Edgelist](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#Read_Edgelist) store the original id's from the the edge list? or under which attribute name?

Assume that I am reading an edge list like:

```
1 2
2 1 
1 3
```

where the numbers `1,2,3` are the ids (or names) of the nodes. Where does the iGraph (python version) stores these ids?
I tried retrieving these Ids from the attribute `name` or `id` but it did not work, as those two attributes, seemingly, must be explicitly defined.

Comment: `my_graph.es` should show the edge sequence of your graph

Comment: I tried that, and using 'source and 'target' i can retrieve the nodes. But still I do not know where these original ids are stored!

Comment: @M.M, I edited my answer to add info on where node ids are stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Read_Edgelist`](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#Read_Edgelist) assumes the node ids are the consecutive integers from 0 to m, where m is the maximum integer in the edge list.  So there is "no need to store node ids."

For example, if your edgelist.txt is `1 3`, this code

```
import igraph as ig
g = ig.Graph.Read_Edgelist("edgelist.txt")
print g.get_adjacency()
```

creates a graph with four nodes (0, 1, 2, 3) and prints

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 1]
 [0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29268262/1628638) if you do not want "intermediate" nodes to be created.

While the following is unnecessary for a graph with consecutive node ids starting with 0, one could access the node ids using [`VertexSeq`](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.VertexSeq-class.html) and [`Vertex`](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Vertex-class.html):

```
for v in g.vs:
  print v.index   # node id
```